# Open new window in WinJS Universal App

Tags: winjs, windows-10-universal

I am trying to figure out how to open a new window from within my WinJS Universal Windows app.

I've found plenty of examples of how to do this in a XAML Universal App using `Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.CreateNewView`, but I can't seem to find a reference to that method within the WinJS or Windows namespaces in my Javascript.  According to code-hints when I am writing my Javascript, I am able to see that there is a `Windows.ApplicationModel.Core` namespace, but the only class that appears in it is `AppListEntry`.  No `CoreApplication` or any of the other classes that [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.core.aspx) suggests should be there.

I've been digging around trying to find out if this is possible.  I haven't been able to find any resources that specifically say you *can't* perform this action in a WinJS app, but I haven't found any examples that show how to do this either.

I downloaded the [Universal Windows App Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples), and they do have a `MultipleViews` project there, but it doesn't include a JS build.

Does anyone know if it is possible to open a new window from within a WinJS app?

Comment: After more searching, I've found [this link](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/01/09/be-two-places-at-once-using-multiple-windows/) that suggests that you can create new windows from a WinJS project.  However, that post is from 2014, and `MSApp.createNewView` returns undefined when I debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens when you do:

```
window.open("http://www.w3schools.com");
```

Or set target as "_blank" as you would do for an HTML window?

```
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">Visit W3Schools</a>
```

There is tool written for the Intel XDK (A Cordova product), which can work around some of the limitations of JS running on Windows. Here is a link: https://github.com/xmnboy/xdk-win8x-compat.js . It may resolve some of these issues.

When I was writing Win8 JS apps, I know that I could wrap a function in:

```
MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction(unsafeFunction);
```

[(documentation)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh767331.aspx), which would allow me to inject JS to the DOM. You *may* be able to write a function that creates a new window with that.

Comment: No luck on that approach, I did try it.  

I found [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700404.aspx) that explicitly states window.open will not work in WinJS apps, along with a slew of other Javascript functions.

Comment: Hmm.. I've updated with more info, hopefully that helps.

Comment: Hmm.  I'll give that a shot.  Was hoping for something more "official" than executing "unsafe" functions, but if it works, it works.  I'll report back after I've tested it.  Thanks!

Comment: Confirmed that I am able to call window.open, and have that launch a new window.  Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, Glad to help!